# Design support of a base for a load bearing vertical struture

Tags: mechanical-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis

I'm designing an elevator system to haul a load of 250 lbs. Did some rough CAD modeling of the system.

I'm looking for some help on how to mount the strut rails (72") such that the structure can sustain the weight itself while not anchored to a wall.

I can work with a rough pencil drawing if someone could draw it. I am thinking of having a wider base as a platform as a starting point, but wondering if there are other ideas.

Motivation came from [https://jayscustomcreations.com/2021/01/diy-elevator/](https://amzn.to/2Mh6cp0) but instead of fastening the struts to a wall (which I don't have liberty) have the frame away from walls.

The plan so far is to use 12 gauge 1-5/8 in. x 1-5/8 as the channel and use Superstrut trolley blocks: https://amzn.to/2Mh6cp0

[image: Basement elevator system]

Comment: Knowing the material the struts would be made from, if steel, what type of steel, & the dimensions of the struts, cross sectional & thickness might be useful to those who might help.

Comment: If you do not wish to attach the rails to the wall, you will need a "foundation" system to counter the rotation of the lift.

Comment: @Fred, Thank you for the reminder. I plan to use [12 Gauge](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Superstrut-1-5-8-in-x-1-5-8-in-Silver-Electroplated-Half-Slot-Channel-Strut/1000192655) from Superstrut that is sold by both Homedepot and Lowes.

Comment: @r13 - That is what  I'm trying to avoid the rotation that could cause the platform to tip over.  I was pondering is to use a deck post (4x4) along with some brackets and mount them using concrete anchors, but my preference is going to have above-ground support. Another thought is to use counterweights by putting cinder blocks on a metal frame (not shown above) but not sure what is the best. I would not want this to move in XY plan.

Comment: You need a rigid frame made of 4 posts and header beams. At the bottom, you will need a heavy slab to support the frame and maintain its stability. The design is not difficult, but a lot of calculations, which you might need helps from a professional.